# Trying to get a Plotly histogram with probability and rug parameters

Tags: python, histogram, plotly-python

I'm using "creditcard.csv" Plotly histogram. I want to use parameters histnorm='probability' and marginal='rug'
Before these parameters, I could run this code

```
fig = px.histogram(df, x="Time", color="Class", histnorm='probability', color_discrete_sequence=["slategray",   "magenta"])
   fig.update_layout(title='Transactions Time Density Plot')
   fig.show()
```

When I run this code;

```
fig = px.histogram(df, x="Time", color="Class", histnorm='probability', color_discrete_sequence=["slategray", "magenta"], marginal="rug", hover_data=["Time", "Class"])
    fig.update_layout(title='Transactions Time Density Plot')
    fig.show()
```

I couldn't get any result even any warning and I had to restart the kernel.
this is the example of the Plotly's site:

```
df = px.data.tips()
    fig = px.histogram(df, x="total_bill", color="sex", marginal="rug", # can be `box`, `violin`
                         hover_data=df.columns)
    fig.show()
```